# Install expo cli errors at the end of install

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

So I'm following this tutorial to try and learn React Native: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSRrxpdMpVc

And in the tutorial he shows to install expo cli using the line

```
'npm install expo-cli --global'
```

But when i run that line, i get a whole bunch of warnings saying for example:

```
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
```

In the tutorial he says to ignore this but at the end of the install i get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-06T01_25_52_024Z-debug.log
```

and then when i try to run the line 'expo init first-app' to create a project i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I also found a similar question with an answer of try running

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g expo-cli
```

So i tried that but it didnt work.

Does anyone know why i would be getting these errors? I tried reinstalling node but that doesnt seem to fix it. Thanks for the help in advance, keep in mind i am completely new to react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have [Node 10 LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or greater installed, you can use npm to install the Expo CLI command line utility:

1. `npm install -g expo-cli`
2. `expo init AwesomeProject`
3. `cd AwesomeProject`
4. `npm start # you can also use: expo start`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work for me, I guess it was glitching with the --global like i was trying but just using -g like you suggested seemed to get the job done. Thank you very much I was getting extremely frustrated by the installer screwing up!